# Bash: Count find result in folder

Tags: bash, find, if-statement

Im trying to count how many files can 'find' the script and if its more than one, give one kind of error message and if its zero give another error msg.

If I run

```
find procesoSitemap-*.jar -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c
```

It works and I can see the number of the search result, but how can I implement that into the script?

```
##!/bin/bash
FINDPS="find procesoSitemap-*.jar -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c"

    if $FINDPS = 1
    then
            echo "There is ONE procesoSitemap jar file"
    else
            echo "There should be only ONE procesoSitemap jar file"
    fi
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use backticks;

```
FINDPS=`find procesoSitemap-*.jar -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c`
```

also fix your `if` line;

```
if [ $FINDPS -eq 1 ]
then
        echo "There is ONE procesoSitemap jar file"
else
        echo "There should be only ONE procesoSitemap jar file"
fi
```

Comment: is giving me the next error: ./run.sh: line 18: 1: command not found
There should be only ONE procesoSitemap jar file
Line 18 is `if $FINDPS = 1`

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a few little problems with your script.  Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FINDPS=`find . -name "procesoSitemap-*.jar" | wc -l`

if [[ $FINDPS == 1 ]] ; then
        echo "There is ONE procesoSitemap jar file"
else
        echo "There should be only ONE procesoSitemap jar file"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement should look like:

```
if (( FINDPS == 1 ))
```

in Bash, or in POSIX `sh`:

```
if [ $FINDPS -eq 1 ]
```

Your variable assignment should be:

```
FINDPS=$(find procesoSitemap-*.jar -exec printf '.' \; | wc -c)
```

in Bash or any POSIX shell. In legacy Bourne `sh`, use backticks:

```
FINDPS=`find procesoSitemap-*.jar -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c`
```

Your shebang for Bash should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

You have one too many '#'.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up the file counting by avoiding `find ... -exec ... \; | ...`:

```
- FINDPS="find procesoSitemap-*.jar -exec printf '.' \;| wc -c"
+ FINDPS="$(find . -name "procesoSitemap-*.jar" -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$()` or ``` `` ```, the former is preferred (and is POSIX) but the latter works in some older shells.